# Will an Apple branded USB-C to USB adapter work on a Windows laptop USB-c port?

Tags: adapter

we ordered a few for some of our end-users. 
These were the "Apple USB-C to USB Adapter"
Model: MJ1M2AM/A

Technically it should work.
Price wise they were cheaper AND the only ones in stock with the retailer we had to use.

Will these work on a Windows laptop with USB-C ?

Comment: They should, all you can do is try one.

Comment: They should work, but keep in mind, that USB-C has many sub protocols, such as thunderbold, displayport, fast ethernet, high power, etc. It depends on what you need and what your laptop supports vs the cable to know if it will fully work

Comment: in this case it would be for data transfer from an Iphone AND using with a USB microphone.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.